# How to close specific file explorer in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

It is fairly easy to close a file explorer based on its window name, like this:

msWinHelper Class:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

    public IntPtr findWindow(string className, string name)
    {
        return FindWindow(className, name);
    }

    public void closeWindow(string className, string windowName)
    {
        SendMessage(findWindow(className, windowName), WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Main program:

```
msWinHelper.closeWindow(null, "WindowName");
```

However in some occasions this is not sufficient. Lets say I have two directories with the same subdirectories. If I open a subdir `DIR1` from parent folder `FOLD1` and another `DIR1` from `FOLD2`, window names become the same. Therefore code cannot determine which is the parent folder and would not necessarily close the one I want.

Is it possible to close an opened folder based on its full path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell has an automation interface that allows enumeration of explorer windows.

Add COM references to shell32.dll and shdocvw.dll then you can:

```
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer window in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
{
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(window.FullName).ToLowerInvariant() == "explorer")
    {
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(window.LocationURL, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            string location = new Uri(window.LocationURL).LocalPath;

            if (string.Equals(location, @"C:\close\me", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                window.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didnt test your code, but isn't `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` an instance of Internet Explorer and not File Explorer?

Comment: It actually includes both, the == "explorer" check filters out any IE windows.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'll need to do more than use `FindWindow` because unfortunately it will always return only one of the Explorer windows (which may not be the one you're looking for).

1. If you want to persist with `FindWindow`, one option you could do is change the Explorer setting options so that the full location path is shown in the title of the window (pretty sure from Windows 8 onwards, you can go to the `View` tab and click on the `Options` button to the far right to tick the `Display the full path in the title bar` setting). 
   [image: Explorer -> View tab -> Options] 
   Once you have this option enabled, then you should be able to supply the folder path to `FindWindow` for it to search for the matching window since it will have the full folder path in the title (assuming that the title bar with that folder path is unique). You may want to check that it is an Explorer window via [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a process ID and use this PID with [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) and check "explorer" is returned in the property [`ProcessName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Alternatively you'll have to find the `Address:` text from the control within the Explorer window itself to work out the exact folder location that the window is showing. *Note: You will need to use a different call to find the other window if the address doesn't match the one you're looking for*. So maybe something like this:

   - use [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) to enumerate all top-level windows;
   - use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) with each top-level window handle and with the returned process ID, use [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) and probably [`ProcessName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname(v=vs.110).aspx) to check that it is an Explorer window;
   - use [`EnumChildWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate controls within the supplied parent window handle (strange name, but apparently all 'controls' are just 'windows' for `winapi`);
   - use [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) to examine the text content for the control and check it matches the folder path you're looking for where it has `Address:` as a prefix;
   - if all the criteria matches, then it should be the window you want to close.

Background on how to find about control details yourself: I usually use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)'s `Au3Info` application to help find such information (also because I usually use AutoIt's scripting language to make a quick prototype for these kind of tasks). Use the 'Finder Tool' by dragging the circular 'aiming' icon over the target Explorer window and address control and release the mouse when you are ready to examine the information for that window/control. Here are some screenshots of what the tool shows when I run it under Windows 10 (details may differ slightly for a different version of Windows). *PS: If you're not bound to C# and happy to learn AutoIt's scripting language, you could also try AutoIt for your task.*

[image: AutoIt's Au3Info Window <code>Visible Text</code> info]
[image: AutoIt's Au3Info 'Address' control <code>Control</code> info]

References:

- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows
- http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Windows/Enumerating_Windows/article.html *(download links broken, but fortunately WaybackMachine to the rescue - [go here to download source code zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20160722135212/http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Windows/Enumerating_Windows/EnumWindows_Code.html))*

Comment: Np. The 'Enumerating Windows' article I referenced has some pretty interesting source code. If WaybackMachine doesn't work for you, I've also uploaded the file via Instant.io [EnumWindows_Code.zip (39 KB)](https://instant.io/#c7c5c42b5d0f8bc32f95cd442ad9f63308eb9f60). 
That said, looks like Alex K.'s solution might be easiest.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using his solution, but I respect the effort you've put in